# Codeigniter 3 error migrations table does not exists

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-migration, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter 3 with many migration files like `001_`, `002_` etc.
Settings in `config/migration.php` are:

```
$config['migration_type'] = 'sequential';
$config['migration_table'] = 'migrations';
$config['migration_auto_latest'] = TRUE;
$config['migration_version'] = '001';
$config['migration_path'] = APPPATH.'migrations/';
```

and code in the Controller:

```
public function index(){
    $this->load->library('migration');

    if($this->migration->current()){
        echo 'done !';
    } else {
        show_error($this->migration->error_string());
    }
}
```

, but when I access the URL `/migrate`, I see this error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1146
>
> Table '{database}.migrations' doesn't exist
>
> SELECT `version` FROM `migrations`
>
> Filename: libraries/Migration.php
>
> Line Number: 414

I used migration from CI3 and before and I know I do not need to create table for migrations, manual, but when you run migrations CI3 do it.
Where is the problem ?

Comment: I've only been testing this using the examples out of the CI User guide which uses a single migration and I cannot fault it. I can drop both the migrations table the the generated table and each time i run it, it works. If I try to break anything to simulate your issue, I get different errors that you would expect... So I am at a bit of a loss on this one. Maybe go back to something simple and work your way back up would be my recommendation.

Comment: Kind of sniffing around this as a suspect $config['migration_auto_latest'] = TRUE; But again on my CI 3.1.0 it still played nice and created the migration and the migrated tables. So I'm obviously not simulating your setup. It'll be something simple!

Comment: I've only been testing this using the examples out of the CI User guide